# Constant terms at each level of a recursion tree

Tags: asymptotics, proof-techniques, recurrence-relation, recursion

In CLRS, exercise 4.4-5 the following question is asked:

> Use a recursion tree to determine a good asymptotic upper bound on the recurrence $$T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n/2) + n$$

In my recursion tree, the sum of level 0 is $$n$$ level 1 is $$(3/2)n - 2/2^1$$ level 2 $$(3/2)^2n-14/2^2$$ level 3 is $$(3/2)^3n - 74/2^3$$
and so on. My issues is that the rule governing the constants 2, 14, 74 etc. is difficult to express as a function of the level so that I can create a sum for all levels of the tree.

Would it be correct to say that the cost at each level of the tree is $$(3/2)^in - O(1)$$
and thus avoid the problem of having to sum all of the constant terms via big O notation, or is this approach incorrect? If so, why and what should I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each specific level $i$, it is true that the cost is $(3/2)^i n - O(1)$. However it would be misleading to state this in general. Suppose for example that the cost at level $i$ were $(3/2)^i n + 2^{2^i}$, and that there were $\log n$ levels. The dominant factor in the total cost would be the "constant" term.

However, in your case, you can say that the cost at level $i$ is *at most* $(3/2)^i$, which gives you the required upper bound.

Comment: In that case, how would you handle cases where such constant terms are added instead of subtracted?

Comment: You need to estimate them as a function of $i$. No way around it.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the recurrence itself. First, for concreteness, let us define $T(0) = 0$ and for $n > 0$,
$$ T(n) = T(n-1) + T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + n. $$
Let $S(n) = T(n) + 2n$. Then
$$ S(n) = T(n) + 2n = T(n-1) + T(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + 3n = S(n-1) + S(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + n+1 - 2\lfloor n/2 \rfloor,$$
and $S(0) = 0$. Note that $n+1-2\lfloor n/2 \rfloor \in \{1,2\}$. Therefore if we define a $R(0) = 0$ and
$$ R(n) = R(n-1) + R(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor) + 1 $$
then $S(n) = \Theta(R(n))$ and so $T(n) = \Theta(R(n)) - 2n$.

Now let $U(n) = R(n) + 1$. Then $U(0) = 1$ and $$U(n) = U(n-1) + U(\lfloor n/2 \rfloor).$$
Thus $U(n)$ is the number of ways to reach $0$ using two operations: subtract $1$ and right shift by $1$. Also, $R(n) = U(n) - 1$, and so $T(n) = \Theta(U(n)) - 2n$, which is going to equal $\Theta(U(n))$.

The sequence $U$ is also known as [A000123](http://oeis.org/A000123), where other interpretations are given. The asymptotics of the sequence are known to be $n^{\Theta(\log n)}$. More accurate answers can be found on the OEIS references.